# Braintree, Java : Check if subscription is valid and paid for.

Tags: java, payment-gateway, braintree

I am working on integrating braintree payments into our Spring-MVC based app. We have subscriptions in our application which are charged on monthly basis unless canceled by the user. However, there might be a situation when the payment doesn't go through on next billing cycle and we would like to cancel the services offered.

The approach I have taken is to get a list of all subscriptions which are currently active and track their status. Based upon that, we either let the service exist or run cancellation code. 
**Is this approach sufficient the way it is mentioned below?**

Code :

```
 @Override
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 4 5 * * ?")
    public void checkIfSubscriptionIsActive() {
        List<Payment> paymentList = this.paymentDAO.getAllPayments();
        for(Payment payment : paymentList){
            Subscription subscription = gateway.subscription().find(payment.getPaypalId());
            if(subscription!=null){
                Subscription.Status status = subscription.getStatus();
                if(status!=null){
                    if(status.toString().equals("Canceled")||(status.toString().equals("Expired"))||
                            (status.toString().equals("Past Due"))||(status.toString().equals("Pending"))||
                            (status.toString().equals("Unrecognized"))){
                        //Cancel service code
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure how Subscription object is constructed but I do not think it be null so there might not be a good thing to check if its null or not. 
Same with a status it should always be a either negative or positive (they either paid for it or not). So there might not be need to check if its null.

Comment: @NashPL : Status is simply an Enum and provided by Braintree for knowing the subscription status.

Comment: Ah it does make sense then. I would consider a try/catch than a IF in this case because if it returns null then there is something wrong with a data returned from Braintree.

Comment: @NashPL : A if block is sufficient in this case as the Status enum is inside Subscription, so if Subscription object is null, it means Status is null as well, which means wrong data from Braintree was received.

Comment: If Subscription.Status is an enum then why don't you just use == for comparison? This way you can ditch the if(status!=null) check and the code would be a bit cleaner.

Comment: @Tarmo : Okay, but the main question is, is this approach sufficient or are there any other API's I can utilize. Thank you. :-)

Comment: @We are Borg Braintree lets you set [retry logic](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/recurring-advanced-settings#automatic-retries) in the Control Panel for scenarios where a recurring charge fails. You could set it up so that you attempt to recharge the customer again after 1 day, if it fails again attempt one more recharge after 1 day, then cancel the subscription.

Comment: @hollabaq : Yes, that's the brain tree part. What about the part on application side mentioned in the question. If I add a retry logic, then mostly in the next check the cancellation service code will run.